# How do you calculate the GAP beween two numbers in Crystal Reports?

Tags: syntax, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

If you have a goal number and an actual number, the easy way to calculate the gap is simply:

```
{goal} - {actual}
```

But if you exceed you goal, then this number will display in the report as a negative number. The convention my boss wants to use is to put a "+" sign in front of the number to recognize we've exceeded the goal.

I've tried writing a formula that multiplies the result by -1 if the result returns negative:

```
shared numbervar gap;
gap := {goal} - {actual}
if gap < 0 then gap := gap * -1
gap;
```

But it doesn't work.

My first question is what am I doing wrong?

My second question would be, is there a better way to do this? Is what I'm calling the Gap known as something else in crystal reports?

Comment: What you're calculating is the _absolute difference_ (I should say, that is what you'd be calculating had you terminated lines 2 and 3 properly with semicolons). But that's not what you want because then your `gap` variable will lose its sign, which you need. You want to just keep `gap:={goal}-{actual}` but just display it in the report with '+' as the negative sign (instead of the '-').

Comment: Why not just reverse the order: `{actual} - {goal}`?

Comment: @craig Because what makes sense and what your boss wants aren't always the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

When you multiply with `-1` that doesn't mean it displays as `+`...it doesn't displays any negative sign means it is a positive number.

Normally in mathematics if there is no sign before number it is considered as positive number no need to explicitly mention as `+`

Now coming you problem.. you have done everything correctly but since you need to see the `+` sign then append it as below

```
shared numbervar gap;
Shared Numbervar display;

gap := {goal} - {actual};

if (gap < 0) 
then display := "+"&ToText(gap * -1)
else display := gap;
display
```

Comment: Lines still aren't terminated properly so this isn't a valid formula. Also, what if `{goal}>={actual}`? You're not accounting for that possibility and are just prepending `+` to everything.

Comment: I was getting a, "A number is expected here" error at your ToText() function.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this using the following formula:

```
shared numbervar gap;

gap := {goal} - {actual};

If gap < 0 then

"+" + totext(gap * -1, 0, "")

Else if gap = 0 then
totext(gap, 0, "")
else

totext(gap, 0, "")
```